# Проблема с установкой высоты блока по родителю

Tags: jquery

Проблема в том, что имеющийся код устанавливает для всех 6-и блоков одну высоту, а надо что бы высота устанавливалась по высоте того ряда в котором находится блок.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var tHeight = $('.Box').parent('.Row').height();
$(".Box").css('height', tHeight);
});
```

каждый .Row содержит два элемента .Box

Comment: не хотите это средствами css реализовать? нужен ли тут скрипт?

Comment: Ряд не может иметь заданной высоты (он её получает от контента), думаю с css не получится.

Comment: чтобы высота разная была, вам цикл нужен по блоками, и выдергивание высоты родителя `$(".Box").each(function(){ var h = $(this).closest(".Row").height(); $(this).css('height', h); });`

Comment: У родителя `position relative`, у блока `position absolute, top 0, left 0, width 100%, height 100%`

Comment: @lampa их там несколько блоков в строке, наверное, left и width не пойдут

Comment: @teran так а строка одной высоты и в ней два блока?

Comment: absolut - не вариант, поскольку высоты у .Row не задано, то всё съедет наверх, так что вариант только с jquery.

Comment: @MaximRadziuk вы бы привели пример верстки лучше.

Comment: @teran, такой вариант пробовал - не работает. Почему-то вообще не задаёт высоту в таком случае, но консолька ошибку не дает.

Comment: верстка проста: 3 ряда .Row, в каждом по 2 блока .Box. Каждый ряд должен иметь высоту самого большого дочернего блока и, соответственно эта высота должна быть присвоена меньшому блоку этого ряда.

Comment: @teran, сорри, я когда свой цикл делал не заметил ошибку в селекторе. Таким образом работает)

Comment: @MaximRadziuk и почему не сделать [к примеру через `table-cell`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_equal_height.asp)?

Comment: или [так](https://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)

Comment: table-cell не хорош тем, что в адаптиве блоки съезжают один под второй.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

чтобы высота разная была, вам цикл нужен по блоками, и выдергивание высоты родителя

```js
$(".Box").each(function() {
  var h = $(this).closest(".Row").height();
  $(this).css('height', h);
});
```